# Error using setVisible() method in order to dispose current frame

Tags: java

I need some help here. I need to open a new window and close the current one when I press a button. I've done this using an anonymous function, which seems not to be working, because I get an error:

> The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Can somebody give me a solution in order for this to work ?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {



        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Login.user = "root";
            Login.pass = "aaaa";
            Login.schema = "bankingdb";

            try {
                conn = MySql.getConnection(user, pass, "/" + schema);
                connection = true;

                try {
                    String q = "select usertype from create_user where username=? and password=?";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(q);
                    stmt.setString(1, userBox.getText());
                    stmt.setString(2, passwordBox.getText());
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    if (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("usertype").equals("Admin")) {
                            AdminMenu adminMenu = new AdminMenu();
                            adminMenu.setVisible(true);
                            this.setVisible(false);
                        } else if (rs.getString("usertype").equals("Employee")) {
                            UserFrame obj = new UserFrame();
                            // obj.setVisible(true);
                            // this.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Invalid Username/Password");
                    }

                    stmt.execute();
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error in Query: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error in connection: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the line I get the error at:

```
this.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `this`?

Comment: Yes, I don't get the error anymore. Thanks.